# Git pushing to repo with existing history (1 commit)

Tags: git

I have this project for which I've used repo started locally (and pushed to a private Github repo, but that is probably besides the question).

Now the client wants the code (with history, obviously) and want it pushed to their own repo, problem being that they created the remote repo with an initial commit (with an empty README) so now there are 2 histories, the project's and the remote's single-commit histories. Client says they can't create a completely empty repo, that at least that initial commit has to exist.

What would be the 'proper' way of pushing to this repository and merge their histories?

ETA: Client has refused the idea of just forcing the push and actually want the code push to be a pull request.

Comment: *"Client says they can't create a completely empty repo"* Client is wrong. `git push -f` to overwrite their history.

Comment: I know they are wrong, but won't budge. Edited question to clarify that and that they actually want a pull request.

Answer (score 0):

Condolences. Anyway, you can force the merge with `--allow-unrelated-histories`:

```
git remote add origin ssh://git@github.com/YourClient/TheRepository
git fetch origin
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/master
git pull --allow-unrelated-histories
git push
```

Comment: I can't quite test this right now, but I believe I tried this (barring setting the upstream of the branch) and git would complain of unrelated histories. Does setting the upstream branch change that?

Comment: @RobertoCuba: Ah, sorry, `git pull --allow-unrelated-histories`.